# Automated cycling of colors in web gallery of clickable images

Tags: html, css

Say I place two images on a page with HTML:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/1">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/2">
```

On mouse-over, I want the 1st image to get a red border, and the 2nd a blue border, so I use this CSS:

```
img { border: 5px solid black; }
img:hover:nth-of-type(2n+1) { border-color: red; }
img:hover:nth-of-type(2n+2) { border-color: blue; }
```

This works. If I add additional images, the colors will still appropriately alternate without any new CSS.  But actually, I want the images to be clickable links, so they should be inside `<a>` tags:

```
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/1"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/animals/2"></a>
```

Now the CSS doesn't do what I want anymore. Both images get a red border on mouse-over, instead of one red, one blue.  I think I get why -- each `<img>` is now the 1st of its type within an `<a>`.  But how do I fix the CSS to work in this case?  On my real page, I'm going to have many more than two images, and I want the border to alternate between red and blue.  I'm hoping to avoid specifying a class or id for each `<img>`. I supposed I'd also prefer to avoid Javascript, which I've never used, if possible.

Here's a jsfiddle page showing this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ad3LdupL/

Thanks for any help, and apologies if this is a duplicate. It seems fairly basic, but I'm new to CSS and I didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your CSS to this and edit as needed:

```
img {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
img:hover {
    border:none;
}
a:hover:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
a:hover:nth-of-type(2n+2) {
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative
}
a:hover {
    top:-5px;
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xp21n859/)

Comment: I assume you mean the 2 top images, but they're not needed anymore as he stated, so I didn't care. Otherwise, he can keep his old code as well for non linked elements

Comment: @Fabio, thanks! It didn't occur to me to apply the border to the `<a>` because I wasn't thinking of it as a physical thing that can have a border, in contrast to the `<img>`, if that makes any sense. I modified your CSS so that the `<img>`s never have a border, and the `<a>`s do all the work.  But I'm still having a kind of nitpicky problem: there's a 5px gap of white space between the bottom of an image and the border, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Here's a new jsfiddle with my modified code: http://jsfiddle.net/xp21n859/3

Comment: Aha! I found a simple fix, changing the `display` property from `inline-block` to `inline-flex`. This was dumb luck -- I have no idea why it works. Here's the new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xp21n859/5/.

Comment: yes, that's why in your code I've added that top:-5px (which equals your border size), you can have it as inline-block or inline-flex, it all depends on the approach you take (in this case I took you had a border on the image, hence the -5px)